# Построение гистограммы (TeeChart) по данным из таблицы (StringGrid) в Delphi

Tags: delphi, stringgrid, teechart

Как построить столбчатую диаграмму (гистограмму) на данных, взятых из таблицы?

Есть динамически формируемая таблица, в которой содержатся некоторые объекты и их свойства (например: наименование, количество, цена и пр.). Задача: взять два столбца из этой таблицы (наименование и цена) и построить гистограмму стоимости для каждого из объектов, где ось X - это наименование объекта, а ось Y - его стоимость.

Раньше с компонентом TeeChart дел не имел. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не вижу проблем. До сих пор считаю, что интерактивная справка Delphi - лучшая из всех IDE. Да, для TeeChart справки в современном Delphi нет, в отличие от древних версий, но компонент интуитивно понятный для использования. В любом случае, документация к нему доступна на [оф. сайте](http://www.teechart.net/docs/)

Итак, чтобы работать с гистограммой, есть два варианта:

1. В режиме конструирования формы: добавить Series типа  Bar во вкладке Series при настройке компонента TChart
2. В runtime-режиме:

---

```
var
  MySeries:TBarSeries;
<...>
begin
<...>
  MySeries:=TBarSeries.Create(Chart1);
   chart1.AddSeries(MySeries);
<...>
```

Теперь, чтобы добавлять данные в диаграмму, достаточно обращаться к методу `TBarSeries.AddBar(Avalue:double; ALabel:string; Acolor:TColor)`. Если нужно при этом брать данные из StringGrid, ничего сложного:

```
for I := 1 to N do
    MySeries.AddBar(StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[1,i]),StringGrid1.Cells[0,i], clRed);
// предполагаю, что в 1й колонке у вас -цена, в нулевой - наименование. clRed - столбцы будут красного цвета, можете менять clRed на любой желаемый.
```